# Subida de archivos con node, express a heroku

Tags: nodejs, express, heroku

Hola tengo una aplicación que estoy subiendo para pruebas, el backend esta hecho en node y lo subí a heroku por medio de github, la base de datos esta en MYSQL y la subi a cleverCloud.

Ahora tengo que subir archivos como imágenes, pdf y audios, ya esa parte esta lista es mas las sube al servidor por medio del endpoint de heroku y después sube a la base de datos la ruta exitosa mente pero no veo donde queda el archivo en heroku.

dejo la imagen de la respuesta en postman

```
{
"ok": true,
"publicacion": {
    "fieldCount": 0,
    "affectedRows": 1,
    "insertId": 109,
    "serverStatus": 2,
    "warningCount": 0,
    "message": "",
    "protocol41": true,
    "changedRows": 0
},
"resarch": {
    "ok": true,
    "archivosSubidos": [
        {
            "path": "./src/archivos/8f7314b7-0cc0-4b9c-a749-a3fc81027af9.png"
        }
    ],
    "err": [
        {
            "ok": false,
            "msg": "extencion no valida",
            "archivo": "FGL 015 Registro de atencion Investigacion Laboratorios.xlsx"
        }
        ]
    }
}
```